# NSwag - Modifying Hosts, Schemes, etc using .NET Framework Global.asax setup

Tags: asp.net, swagger-ui, openapi, nswag

I'm trying to modify the Host, Schemes, BasePath, etc properties on the Swagger Document object. I'm using a Global.asax ASP.NET setup (not Core), setting up the properties through UseSwaggerUi3.

I have tried modifying these properties through a Document Processor, as well as SwaggerUi3Settings.PostProcess, but neither of those have any affect on the aforementioned properties.

I have seen in NSwag GitHub issues that these properties should be added in the PostProcess of UseOpenApi or AddOpenApiDocument, but those methods don't seem to be available using the Global.asax setup.

Answer (score 0):

In nswag for web api you can set it on the settings object of UseSwaggerUi3()